# How to trigger a "touchEnter" event with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, touch, drag

My DOM is roughly.

```
   <SomeContainer>
     <Foo/>
     <Bar/>
   </SomeContainer>
```

When I touch Foo and move my finger over Bar, I want to trigger an event and do things in Bar, similar to if I had bound onDrag for Foo and onDragOver for Bar.

Is there any way to do this without resolving to stupid hacks like getting the coordinates from the touchmove events and then somehow resolving the element the touch is moving over?

Comment: My guess is your either going to have to code it your self, or use the drag and touch abstractions in some library, like hammerjs, jquery touch, etc. At least with the libraries the hacks have been tested thoroughly.

Comment: Went with the stupid hack for now, at least managed without external bloatware.